# :only-of-type not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given the following markup:

```
<div>
    <p class="eventPerformanceDate">...</p> 
    <p class="eventPerformance">...</p>
</div>
```

I want to target the `.eventPerformance` paragraph if it is the only `.eventPerformance` paragraph within the div.

I am using the following CSS to try to do this but it is not working:

```
.eventPerformance:only-of-type {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

I am misunderstanding how `:only-of-type` works?

Comment: You're looking for `only-of-class` which, like `nth-of-class`, does not exist, You need javascript,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like all the other CSS `*-of-type` selectors, the `only-of-type` selector works on the element's type and not the extra conditions attached with it. Here there are two elements of type `p` within the parent and hence it has no effect.

A selector like `.eventPerformance:only-of-type` means that an element which is the only one of its type under the parent must be selected and styled if it ***also has*** `class='eventPerformance'`. It ***does not mean select the only element with `class='eventPerformance'`*** and style it.

In the snippet, you can see how the selector affects the `p` within the second `div` wrapper as it has only one `p` element. It also affects the `p` within the third `div` wrapper because even though there are two elements with `class='eventPerformance'` there is still only one element of type `p` with that class. The `h4` within the third `div` wrapper also gets selected because there is only one element of its type within the parent and it too has the class.

The `only-of-type` selector will select ***the only element of every single type*** as long as there is no type selector attached to it (like `p:only-of-type`, `p.eventPerformance:only-of-type`etc).

In the fourth `div` wrapper, the `p` tag is not styled even though it is the only one of its type because it doesn't match the other half of the condition (that is, the class selector is not matched).

```css
p, h4 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.eventPerformance:only-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>None of the elements selected - Not only one of its type</h3>
<div>
  <p class="eventPerformanceDate">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p class="eventPerformance">Paragraph 2</p>
</div>

<h3>Element is selected - Only p and has required class</h3>
<div>
  <p class="eventPerformance">Paragraph 1</p>
</div>

<h3>Elements are selected - Both are only element of their type and have class</h3>
<div>
  <h4 class="eventPerformance">Heading 1</h4>
  <p class="eventPerformance">Paragraph 1</p>
</div>

<h3>Element is not selected - Only p but doesn't have required class</h3>
<div>
  <p class="some-other-class">Paragraph 1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Small point, but the third example is potentially a little misleading - the `h4` *also* gets selected and the style is applied, but you can't see at a glance that you've added `border-bottom: none` because it already has no `border-bottom`. Was going to suggest something like that as a useful example of having two `only-of-type` elements in the same container

Comment: @CupawnTae Fair point mate. I agree that it is a bit misleading. I will edit the answer to make it clearer when I get back to my PC (commenting via phone).